# what would be the proper way to add multiple functions to the jquery $(window).load function declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using the following javascript to animate two slideshows using the nivo slider object in jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('#sliderone').nivoSlider({  
        effect:'fade',  
        slices:15,  
        animSpeed:500,  
        pauseTime:7000,  
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)  
        directionNav:false, //Next & Prev  
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover  
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...  
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav  
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...  
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src  
        keyboardNav:false, //Use left & right arrows  
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering  
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions  
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity  
        beforeChange: function(){},  
        afterChange: function(){},  
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown  
    });  
});  
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('#slidertwo').nivoSlider({  
        effect:'fade',  
        slices:15,  
        animSpeed:500,  
        pauseTime:7000,  
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)  
        directionNav:false, //Next & Prev  
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover  
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...  
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav  
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...  
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src  
        keyboardNav:false, //Use left & right arrows  
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering  
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions  
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity  
        beforeChange: function(){},  
        afterChange: function(){},  
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

This code works in internet explorer but not in chrome/firefox. I suspect it is because I am using the $(window).load(function() twice/incorrectly.

Any advice on how this can be properly done would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code of the both callbacks is nearly identical, I would refactor it to:

```
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('#sliderone, #slidertwo').nivoSlider({  
        effect:'fade',  
        slices:15,  
        animSpeed:500,  
        pauseTime:7000,  
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)  
        directionNav:false, //Next & Prev  
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover  
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...  
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav  
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...  
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src  
        keyboardNav:false, //Use left & right arrows  
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering  
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions  
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity  
        beforeChange: function(){},  
        afterChange: function(){},  
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown  
    });  
});
```

Also consider to use the document ready event instead: `$(document).ready(function(){...})` or short `$(function(){...})`.

Starx mentioned to use a class instead of IDs, which is also a good advice!

---

Assuming that both sliders should look and work exactly the same, this code makes it way more easier to make changes to them, as you only have make the change **once** (increases maintainability and readability).

Comment: This seemed to be the best answer to my question as it also decreased the amount of redundant code. Thank you very much Sir!

Answer (score 2):

You only need one declaration of window.load and you can put both functions into it.

```
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('#sliderone').nivoSlider({  
        effect:'fade',  
        slices:15,  
        animSpeed:500,  
        pauseTime:7000,  
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)  
        directionNav:false, //Next & Prev  
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover  
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...  
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav  
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...  
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src  
        keyboardNav:false, //Use left & right arrows  
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering  
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions  
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity  
        beforeChange: function(){},  
        afterChange: function(){},  
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown  
    });   
    $('#slidertwo').nivoSlider({  
        effect:'fade',  
        slices:15,  
        animSpeed:500,  
        pauseTime:7000,  
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)  
        directionNav:false, //Next & Prev  
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover  
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...  
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav  
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...  
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src  
        keyboardNav:false, //Use left & right arrows  
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering  
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions  
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity  
        beforeChange: function(){},  
        afterChange: function(){},  
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call both functions inside the load function. Perhaps it is better to let jQuery decide when the document is loaded by using the syntax below.

```
$(function() {

    $("#Slider1"). ..

    $("#Slider2"). ..

});
```

Comment: Which browser has no window object? I think every browser has. Firefox definitely has ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using class instead of id. Looks likes all the options are same so you dont need to use the same code twice. Try using class and queuing up multiple window.load function dont create any trouble

Like this

```
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('.sliders').nivoSlider({  
        effect:'fade',  
        slices:15,  
        animSpeed:500,  
        pauseTime:7000,  
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)  
        directionNav:false, //Next & Prev  
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover  
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...  
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav  
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...  
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src  
        keyboardNav:false, //Use left & right arrows  
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering  
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions  
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity  
        beforeChange: function(){},  
        afterChange: function(){},  
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown  
    });  
});
```

Now give both yours sliders class `sliders`

Comment: You answer was a working answer, I upvoted but had to give the accepted answer to the one which further simplified the code.
Thank you!